# What is wrong with my config/routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I'm using the ruby 2.1.2p95 version, and I'm running into some problems following directions to this tutorial (http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html) on creating a blog.

I followed exactly what the tutorial said, up until the step "Setting up the router." Once I open config/router.rb, the first line in my document is "Rails.application.routes.draw do," not "Blogger::Application.routes.draw do."

The reason I'm asking is in the tutorial on Jump Start Lab, after I continued to the "Creating Template Step," I received a different error message from "Template missing...". I got "Unknown actions...", and eventually, I couldn't view the index page.

I also looked at another tutorial on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GQmC-8k09c), and I got the same problem, where the config/router.rb's first line remains the same.

1. Do you know why this is happening?
2. Am I supposed to manually change the first line from "Rails.application..." to "[Name of app]::Application.routes.draw do"?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Something seems to have gone amiss.

Answer (score 0):

I try with Rails 4.0.4, and it's `Blogger::Application.routes.draw do` but with rails 4.1.4 it's `Rails.application.routes.draw do`. I didn't see any news about new router api, so it should be same.

But if you wanna follow tutorial then you can make:

```
gem uninstall rails
```

and remove rails 4.1.* then install rails 4.0 with command

```
gem install rails -v 4.0.8
```